# Calendar entries that live in Exchange 2010 cannot be edited

Tags: calendar, exchange

After setting up mail and calendar synchronization with our Exchange server (Exchange 2010) and the built-in app, I cannot edit the entries in the Exchange calendar. Adding new entries works fine.

[Comment #15](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13779#c15) of a Google code issue shows an important hint. It works when the "primary E-mail address" is used when connecting to the account.

Could there be other reasons? How do I find the primary E-mail address (short of asking the system administrator)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the primary e-mail address from my phone: In the details of an appointment, I was listed as attendee under an e-mail address different from the one the account was configured for, and the e-mail address of this attendee turned out to be my primary e-mail address.

I was unable to change the e-mail address for the existing account. After dropping and recreating the account using the primary e-mail address, I can now update details of all appointments on my device.

Answer (score 0):

Although this was posted some time ago, it still seems to be an issue for many. So here is what I found out.

I also use Exchange 2010 and had a similar issue with one twist: I was using my primary email and not the alias. I had to remove the account and reconfigure it with the alias that created the entry. I was able to then edit entries created on other devices (eg PC, tablet, etc) that used that alias. BUT, if it is created with any other aliases (of which I have several), it cannot be edited. So it's not necessarily finding your primary email address; it's about finding which email address created it. That can be found by going to the details of the entry and the email that was used by the 'host' of the event is the email address that has to be used in setting up the account on the device for the device to be able to edit the entry.